# Can I put the property visible to an icon that is inside a text? SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, text, icons, sapui5, formatter

What I'm trying to do is put in only column the information about the hour, date and an icon that indicates if something changed in the last hour. So I need that this icon only show in the web when the value is not null. I can do this in the same column?

this is my web right now in two differents columns:

[image]

and what I need is all this information in only ONE column

this is my code:

view:

```
    <Table id="tablaPacientes" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" width="auto" alternateRowColors="true" items="{path: '/EspCoSet'}">
                    <columns>
                        <Column hAlign="Center" width="5%">
                            <Text text="{i18n>ColumnaHoraMedicacion}"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column hAlign="Center" width="5%">
                            <Text text="Alerta"/>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem id="itemsPat">
                            <Text text="{ parts: [ { path: 'Hora' }, {path: 'Fecha'} ], formatter: '.formatter.getHora' }"></Text>
                            <core:Icon src="sap-icon://syringe" visible="{= ${Chora} === true}"></core:Icon>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
```

formatter:

```
getHora: function (hora, fecha) {
            if (hora) {
                var timeFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getTimeInstance({
                    pattern: "HH:mm:ss"
                });
                var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getTimeInstance({
                    pattern: "dd/MM"
                });
                var TZOffsetMs = new Date(0).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
                var value = timeFormat.format(new Date(hora.ms + TZOffsetMs));
                var value2 = dateFormat.format(fecha);
                
                if (value2 !== "00/00") {
                    return value + "\n" + value2;
                }
                else {
                    return 'No tiene medicación';
                }
            }
        },
        
        getIcon: function(Chora) {
            if (Chora === false){
                return "sap-icon://syringe";
            }
        }
```

I tried to put this in the view but didn't work:

```
<Text text="{ parts: [ { path: 'Hora' }, {path: 'Fecha'} ], formatter: '.formatter.getHora' }" icon="{ path: 'Chora', formatter: '.formatter.getIcon' }"></Text>
```

Any idea? Maybe is not possible put the property visible in this case...Thank you so much

Comment: You can wrap your Text and Icon in a HBox. This way ColumnListItem has only one child and will render it as one column

Comment: @Marc Thank you so much, this works. But I have a question...is possible give a space between the text and icon? they show very close.

Comment: @Marc I found a solution "<HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween">"

Comment: @kyara following might also help you for future developments: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.28.33/docs/guide/777168ffe8324873973151dae2356d1c.html